# nodejs callback issue.. not a function

Tags: node.js

I am currently learning NodeJS and working on a mini app, trying to understand callback. However I keep getting the error:

```
  callback(undefined,price);
      ^TypeError: callback is not a function
```

This is my code :

```
var getCoin = (coin, callback) => {

  request({url:`https://https://rest.coinapi.io/${coin}&ssr=USD`,

  json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {


    if(error){
      callback("error");

    }
    else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      let price = body.RAW[coin].USD.PRICE;
      callback(undefined,price);

    }
  })
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  coin.getCoin('BTC', ()=> {
    res.render('index.hbs', {
      coin:'Bitcoin',
      price: coin.getCoin('BTC')

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is this the exact code? `callback` doesn't take any arguments, yet you're trying to give it 1 and 2 arguments.

Comment: How does `getCoin` magically become a property of `coin`?

Comment: @RaphaMex Sorry, I did not show the code properly. I exported the file. Question solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    coin.getCoin('BTC', (err, price)=> {
        res.render('index.hbs', {
            coin:'Bitcoin',
            price: price

        });
    });
});
```

I am assuming `coin.getCoin` accepts two arguments, second argument is callback which itself needs to accept args to work properly. Now in `app.get('/'` you called `coin.getCoin` and passed an anonymous function that will be treated as callback for it, if `coin.getCoin` does its job correctly then `price` will have the value that will eventually be passed to `index.hbs` and `res.render` will do the rest job.